# PHP Dropdown filter to show one or two image input field

Tags: javascript

I create form for "Proof of document" uploader . Where I have ID card front and back side and bill image upload. I Create Dropdown when I click bill that will show one image uploader and when I click on ID it will show 2 image uploader for front and back side image . Can you tell where is my error ?

```
<select>
<option>ID</option>
<option>Bill</option>
</select>
```

When I click on "ID" result I need 2 image uploader

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="front-side">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="back-side">
```

When I click on "Bill" result only I need 1 image uploader

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="user-bill">
 


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#carm3").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() === 'other'){ 
            jQuery('input[name=user-bill]').show();
                    } else {
            jQuery('input[name=front-side]').hide();
jQuery('input[name=back-side]').hide(); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You did not show any JS code. How can we help you when we do not see what can be wrong.

Comment: Hi, Is there any console error?
I think "#carm3" is ths id of Dropdown element yes?

Comment: yes , when i click on BIll i need to show only one input all other hide and when I click on ID it will show 2 input fields,, but error occurred

Comment: check the answer. Hope you're seeking something like this.

Comment: What's that error? Can you show it here?

Comment: no fiields display

Comment: Fields are hidden by CSS. If you want to keep default option selected then you suppose to update JS code and remove CSS.
Did you check "Run Code Snippet"?

Comment: yes its working on "run code snippet"... but I add this css code in style sheet but on select all 3 input fields visible ? can  I embed in to <style></style> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like

```
<select id="carm3"> <!-- You missed id here -->
<option value="">Select</option> <!-- WHen you getting value from option in your code there is not value added -->
<option value="ID">ID</option> <!-- Value of this option is ID -->
<option value="other">Bill</option> <!-- Value of this option is other -->
</select>
```

Your HTML should be like

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="front-side">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="back-side">

<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="user-bill">
```

Now you JS code should be like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#carm3").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == 'other'){
            jQuery('input[name=user-bill]').show(); // show use bill if user pick bill 
            jQuery('input[name=front-side]').hide(); // Hide front side 
            jQuery('input[name=back-side]').hide(); // hide back side 
        } else if ( jQuery(this).val() == 'ID' ) {
            jQuery('input[name=user-bill]').hide(); // Hide user bill 
            jQuery('input[name=front-side]').show(); // Show front side 
            jQuery('input[name=back-side]').show(); // show back side 
        } else {
            jQuery('input[name=user-bill]').hide(); 
            jQuery('input[name=front-side]').hide(); 
            jQuery('input[name=back-side]').hide();     
        }
    }); 
});
```

Add following CSS into your CSS file that is being loaded into the page to hide all File fields until any option get selected from dropdown

```
.custom-file-input { diplay: none; }
```

It's upto you how you want to manipulate unltimately but this is how the code works.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#carm3").change(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == 'other'){
            jQuery('input[name=user-bill]').show(); // show use bill if user pick bill 
            jQuery('input[name=front-side]').hide(); // Hide front side 
            jQuery('input[name=back-side]').hide(); // hide back side 
        } else if ( jQuery(this).val() == 'ID' ) {
            jQuery('input[name=user-bill]').hide(); // Hide user bill 
            jQuery('input[name=front-side]').show(); // Show front side 
            jQuery('input[name=back-side]').show(); // show back side 
        } else {
            jQuery('input[name=user-bill]').hide(); 
            jQuery('input[name=front-side]').hide(); 
            jQuery('input[name=back-side]').hide();     
        }
    }); 
});
```

```css
.custom-file-input { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="carm3"> <!-- You missed id here -->
<option value="">Select</option> <!-- WHen you getting value from option in your code there is not value added -->
<option value="ID">ID</option> <!-- Value of this option is ID -->
<option value="other">Bill</option> <!-- Value of this option is other -->
</select>


<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="front-side">
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="back-side">

<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="user-bill">
```